# NSAttributedString Strikethrough does not draw over entire length of text

Tags: nstableview

I am inserting an NSAttributedString into an NSTableView, and depending on it's content I am adding attributes to its style dictionary.

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {


NSAttributedString *theValue;
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[attributes setObject:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:11] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
currentObject = [ticketsDataSource objectAtIndex:rowIndex];

if ([[currentObject valueForKey:aTableColumn.identifier] isKindOfClass:([NSString class])]) {

    NSString *currentValue = [currentObject valueForKey:aTableColumn.identifier];

    if ([currentValue isEqualToString:@"resolved"]) {

        [attributes setObject:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.344 green:0.619 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

    }

    if ([previousValue isEqualToString:@"resolved"]) {

        [attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlinePatternSolid | NSUnderlineStyleSingle] forKey:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName];
    }

    theValue = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:currentValue attributes:attributes];
    previousValue = currentValue;

}
```

As you can see, basically what happens is when it writes a string called "resolved" it knows that the very next column, which is the title column, gets a strikethrough. It works just fine, but for whatever reason, the strikethrough is not drawing over the entirety of the text!

Here is an image:

[image]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another weirdness with layer-backing. So I turned it off :(